# Declaring floats in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new to `Objective-C` and I'm having trouble with the whole `nonatomic`, `strong`, `weak`, etc. I'm wondering if I will have any issues using `Core Data` with `float` values which are defined like so:

```
@property (nonatomic) float * rating;
@property (nonatomic) float * mRating;
```

Should I declare the differently?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, you should declare them without asterisks:

```
@property (nonatomic) float rating;
@property (nonatomic) float mRating;
```

Asterisks indicate *pointers*. All Objective C classes are declared with asterisks, because instances are referred to through pointers. Primitives such as `float`s, `int`s, etc. are defined as *values*, i.e. without asterisks. Same goes for typedef-ed types such as `CGFloat` and `NSInteger`: scalar fields of these types should be defined without an asterisk.

Comment: You should also use `CGFloat` instead of `float`.

Comment: Great! Thanks! Just out of curiosity, why do you not want to use asterisks?

Comment: @Blaine - Because the asterisk is an entirely different beast - a pointer vs a simple "scalar value".  If you don't understand the difference you really need to study up on pointers and objects before you go any further with Objective-C.

Comment: If you are using Core data it should be declared as NSNumber since it should be an object.

Comment: @Joshua - not true, CoreData can export properties as scalars.

Comment: @sapi Yes it can, but you have to turn it on with an explicit flag in the model, and it's generally more appropriate to use NSNumber because of how opaque it is as a data type.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely lose the `*`, unless you are meaning to create a pointer. Outside of that it looks great!